# c# Excel позднее связывание Find

Tags: c#, excel, com

Как на C# с Excel использовать метод Find через позднее связывание?

Делаю так. Всё работает только с одним параметром **what**. Как использовать остальные параметры? Выбивают исключения при любой попытке использовать остальные параметры поиска.

```
object[] args = new object[1];
args[0] = "привет";  //what
// args[1] = 0;       //after
// args[2] = "";      //LookIn
// args[3] = "";      //LookAt
// args[4] = "";      //SearchOrder
// args[5] = "";      //SearchDirection
// args[6] = "";      //MatchCase
// args[7] = null;    //MatchByte
// args[8] = null;    //SearchFormat

object res = rangeObject.GetType()
                        .InvokeMember("Find",
                           BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, rangeObject, args);
```

Answer (score 1):

При работе с Interop библиотеками, если значение параметра отсутствует обычно передается значение `Missing.Value`, вот пример передаваемых значений в метод `Range.Find()`:

```
        object[] args = new object[9];
        args[0] = "привет";
        args[1] = Missing.Value;
        args[2] = XlFindLookIn.xlValues;
        args[3] = Missing.Value;
        args[4] = Missing.Value;
        args[5] = XlSearchDirection.xlNext;
        args[6] = false;
        args[7] = false;
        args[8] = Missing.Value;
```